# Overlapping letters in the div tag

Tags: html, css, overlay

I wanted to overlap letters in div tags by overlaying both tags like below
(one with the span tags for each letter).

But both letters in different tags are overlapped exactly.

There some mismatchs. How can I solve it?

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="original" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); z-index:1; position:absolute;">Lorem Ipsum is simply</div>
  <div id="copyed" style=" z-index:0; position:absolute; "><span>L</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>e</span><span>m</span><span> </span><span>I</span><span>p</span><span>s</span><span>u</span><span>m</span><span> </span><span>i</span><span>s</span><span> </span><span>s</span><span>i</span><span>m</span><span>p</span><span>l</span><span>y</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that spam stacking is killing me. I'm working on a fiddle at the moment. 

Plus your question doesn't make a lot of sense, are you trying to overlap the text or overlap each letter in the text?

Comment: yes. I want to. Well, without double layer, i felt difficult to make highlighter. I want to make multiple select & highlight with class CSS.

Comment: add `#copyed{top:50px;}` and you will move the `copyed` div *50px* below the first div.

Comment: not getting your question, you may try http://letteringjs.com/ . Hope you will find required  effect that you want.

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve?